# Check what's broken after hard-booting Ubuntu VM

Tags: 14.04, vmware-player

My Ubuntu Virtual Machine has gone through hell. 1 year old, and I'm always running out of memory, meaning it crashes constantly. VMware player has also failed to boot it a few times, and I've had to force quit all VM processes, reboot and hold down the left shift key to get GRUB, only then realizing I should be holding down my right <kbd>shift</kbd> key etc.

Anyway, the VM is absolutely fine, but I am slight concerned that it may be damaged in some way after all this abuse.

Lenses don't work properly, for example. I can only search social network messages for some reason.

I don't have the original ISO and don't have room to download it again, but I'm wondering if there are any commands I can run to maintain Ubuntu? Detect if anything's wrong and redownload certain packages, including default 'inbuilt' applications and things?

Might be a vague question, but is there a single awesome application out there to check if anything's broken and repair it? Or an application Ubuntu has already?

Comment: it is a bit unclear what your actual question is... do you need to assign more memory to your VM? More drive space? More stable applications?

Comment: I am not sure if there is an application out there which can help you with what you are looking for, however, there are boot and kernel logs stored at `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/boot.log`, etc. which might give hints if there is something seriously wrong. As for the lenses, there are quite a few questions with the exact same problem, albeit they might not necessarily be on VMs(but that is immaterial- the problem and the solution are independent of that condition). Just break down your question to something really specific, so it can be solved with a specific subject- this is very broad.